# Keras installation failed even when Anaconda is installed?

Tags: python, r, anaconda

I'm trying to use the Keras framework in R, but I'm seeing this error:

```
`Error: Keras installation failed (no conda binary found)

`Install Anaconda for Python 3.x (https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows)
before installing Keras
```

I've installed Anaconda on my computer and restarted Rstudio, but the error remains. What do I have to do to *link* R and Anaconda?

I'm running Windows 8 and installed both Anaconda and RStudio via their respective official download pages. All Anaconda  binaries are currently sitting  installed in my Apps folder and I need to know where to put it so it will be in my path.

Comment: You did install Python 3.x and not Python 2.x? And Anaconda is in your PATH?

Comment: It's definitely python 3.x, but I'm really a math guy who just started programming so I'll need to be led through the process of making sure anaconda is in my path -- that's why I posted this question.

Comment: Can you update your question to include OS details and how you installed R/RStudio (e.g. via conda, or independently).

Comment: Can you `echo %PATH%` (from the Windows command prompt) before and after you `activate` your conda environment (in your conda command prompt based on whatever name you gave your Python 3 environment). Activation should add the environment to your PATH.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, glad it worked.